# Material Design Lite plugin regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, material-design

I'm working on form based on material-design-lite plugin.
Link below:
https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section

I have a problem with form validation, especially with regular expression.

There is my simple form:

```
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="sample4">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample4">Number...</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

I would like to have such validation patterns:

1. Input amount is not a string (only number 0-9)
2. Separator must be ","
3. I need max 2 decimal places
4. I can't accept any characters, except of
   numbers 0-9 and ","
5. Input amount cannot be less than 0
6. Input amount has to start from a number

Could you please help me with these regular expressions? I don't have enough knowledge about it, just need ready patterns. Rest of validation I'm going to do via javascript.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]*?,?[0-9]{0,2}|[0](?:,[0-9]{0,2})?|)$
```

This seems to match all of the criteria you have provided,
you can test it with this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dPM95O/3)

It consists of 3 "parts" separated by `|`s essentialy testing for 3 different matches

1. `[1-9][0-9]*?,?[0-9]{0,2}` - Matches if the input is a number starting from 1-9 followed by an amount (or lack) of numbers from 0-9 followed then by an optional `,`+ 0-2 numbers from 0-9
2. `[0](?:,[0-9]{0,2})?` - Matches if the input is 0 followed by an optional `,` and 0-2 numbers from 0-9
3. (The lack of anything between the `|` and the `)$` at the end) - Matches if the input is empty

**EDIT: Here is a version which doesn't allow the last character to be a `,` https://regex101.com/r/dPM95O/4**

Comment: What about the max 2 decimal places?

Comment: Thank you, it's great solution!

And what about such situation when comma is the last character? For example: "12,"?

Comment: @bigmeister : this doesn't solve your all conditions.

Comment: @NitinDhomse If you read the conditions it says, and I quote, "Input amount cannot be **less than** 0", which is technically saying it can be 0

Comment: @bigmeister : Decimal places means  maximum digits accepted after decimal point (.), if you want amount max 2 digits then this is fine!

Comment: @bigmeister I did not include this functionality because I do not know if your application would automatically stop allowing input if someone tried to type a "," because it thinks the input would be wrong and doesnt give them time to add a number after the ",", however, if you would like, I can add this

Comment: @NopeNope Yes, please :)

Comment: @bigmeister I have added it to the bottom of my answer